# How to add a fade effect when changing img

Tags: jquery

I am going through an array of images on click and need two things:

1) The current image fade out and the new image fades in (see demo, click forward)

2) Prevent the clicks from incrementing if the button is clicked more than once .. i think I need to use .stop() for this i just don't know how.

here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8Y6dq/2/

HTML

```
<figure>
    <img src="coast.png" />
    <figcaption>Photography</figcaption>
    <nav>
        <a href="#">Back</a>
        <a href="#">Forward</a>
    </nav>
</figure>
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
    var images = [
        "water.png",
        "view.png",
        "sunset.png",
        "coastal.png"
    ],
        $img = $("figure img"),
        $i = 0,
        $j = images.length,
        $back = $("nav a").first(),
        $forward = $("nav a + a");


    $forward.click(function(){
        $i = ($i + 1) % images.length;
        $img.fadeOut().prop("src", images[$i]).fadeIn();
    });

    $back.click(function(){
        $j -= 1;
        if($j >= 0) {
            $img.prop("src", images[$j]);
        } else {
            $j += $j + 1;
        }
    });    

});
```

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7kumE/1/ ?

Comment: hmm that does work but it requires two clicks ..

Comment: `preventDefault()` is what you need to accomplish your 2nd task..

Comment: @user2129623 no... if there is already a transition in progress then the click will be ignored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(function () {
    var images = [
        "http://linenwoods.com/test/water.png",
        "http://linenwoods.com/test/view.png",
        "http://linenwoods.com/test/sunset.png",
        "http://linenwoods.com/test/coastal.png"],
        $img = $("figure img"),
        $i = 0,
        $back = $("nav a").first(),
        $forward = $("nav a + a"),
        flag = false;

    //preload all the images
    $.each(images, function (i, src) {
        new Image().src = src;
    })

    $forward.click(function () {
        //return if already a transition is in progress
        if (flag) {
            return;
        }
        $i = ($i + 1) % images.length;
        //start the switch animation
        swicth();
    });

    $back.click(function () {
        //return if already a transition is in progress
        if (flag) {
            return;
        }
        $i -= 1;
        //rollback to last if the current image is the first one
        if ($i < 0) {
            $i = images.length;
        }
        //start the switch animation
        swicth();
    });

    function swicth() {
        //set the flag to true to indicate a transition
        flag = true;
        $img.fadeOut(function () {
            //use a callback to change the src so that the fade in will be visible
            $img.prop("src", images[$i]).fadeIn(function () {
                //set the flag to false to indicate end of transition
                flag = false;
            });
        });
    }

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7kumE/)

Answer (score 1):

I have updated you code to work on forward link only

```
jsfiddle.net/8Y6dq/3/
```

I have added jquery version there. Also added class when user clicks on the link once and check it to solve your 2nd issue